# Pushing Wordpress to its limits with advanced meta query filtering

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

Here is the situation, we have built quite a complex Wordpress site, whereby we have users who register and login to access pages on the site, with pages and assets in multiple post types all having taxonomies and custom meta fields assigned to them to manage whether or not a user should have access to a page / asset.

Here is my current setup that is working:

Custom Post Type of **Company**

Users are assigned a **Company** object via **Advanced Custom Fields field**.

Each **Company** has one taxonomy of **“Type”** assigned to it.

Each page and other custom post used on the site also has this taxonomy, which is used to filter which company types should see which content when browsing the site.

For one post type, we use this taxonomy filter (tax_query) but also a meta query as well, as we can also pick specific companies from the Company post type to be able to see certain posts. This is currently working with the function below that is being used to filter the search results query (as an example):

```
/* Filter the search results by company type */
function filter_search_results($query){
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ($query->is_search()) {
            $filter = array();
            $companytype = get_current_user_companytype(); // custom function to grab type taxonomy from current users company
            $vfuser = get_user_details(); // custom function to get current users details
            $companyid = intval($vfuser['companyid']); // get the users company id
            if ($companyid){
                $filter[] = array('taxonomy' => 'companytype', 'field' => 'name', 'terms' => $companytype);
            }
            $tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND', $filter);
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
            $meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR', array(
                'key' => 'company_select',
                'value' => '"' . $companyid . '"',
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'company_select',
                        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'company_select',
                        'value'   => false,
                        'compare' => '='
                    )
            ) );
            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 24 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_search_results' );
```

Now, what I want to do is take this a step further and allow for assets to be filtered by specific users, which would then override the above and only show the asset to users that are selected for that post.

I have a custom post meta field created and a form which has all users on the site listed and this is working and submitting an array of user ID’s into the field that can be checked against for each post, but the meta query becomes so complex that it causes a 504 timeout. Below is the query I’ve written up, does anyone have any advice or a simpler way of doing this please it would be very much appreciated.

```
/* Filter the search results by company type */
function filter_search_results($query){
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ($query->is_search()) {
            $filter = array();
            $companytype = get_current_user_companytype(); // custom function to grab type taxonomy from current users company
            $vfuser = get_user_details(); // custom function to get current users details
            $companyid = intval($vfuser['companyid']); // get the users company id
            if ($companytype){
                $filter[] = array('taxonomy' => 'companytype', 'field' => 'name', 'terms' => $companytype);
            }
            $tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND', $filter);
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
            $meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR', array(
                array(
                    // Users exist
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                      'key' => 'comms_users',
                      'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'comms_users',
                        'value' => serialize(strval(get_current_user_id())),
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    // Companies exist but Users do not
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                          'key' => 'comms_users',
                          'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                        ),
                        array(
                          'key'     => 'comms_users',
                          'value'   => false,
                          'compare' => '='
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'company_select',
                        'value' => '"' . $companyid . '"',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    // Company and User select do not exist
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                          'key' => 'company_select',
                          'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                        ),
                        array(
                          'key'     => 'company_select',
                          'value'   => false,
                          'compare' => '='
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                          'key' => 'comms_users',
                          'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                        ),
                        array(
                          'key'     => 'comms_users',
                          'value'   => false,
                          'compare' => '='
                        )
                    )
                )
            ) );
            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 24 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_search_results' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it is useful to anyone in the future (I know it is quite a bespoke request but you never know) I have managed to find a query where the solution works and isn't too intensive on the server.

Final code used is below:

```
/* Filter the search results by partner type */
function filter_search_results($query){
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ($query->is_search()) {
            $filter = array();
            $companytype = get_current_user_ companytype();
            $vfuser = get_user_details();
            $companyid = intval($vfuser['companyid']);
            if ($companytype){
                $filter[] = array('taxonomy' => 'companytype', 'field' => 'name', 'terms' => $companytype);
            }
            $tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND', $filter);
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
            $meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR',
                // Company exists and no users selected
                array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'company_select',
                            'value' => '"' . $companyid . '"',
                            'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'relation' => 'OR',
                            array(
                                'key' => 'company_select',
                                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                            ),
                            array(
                                'key'     => 'company_select',
                                'value'   => false,
                                'compare' => '='
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'comms_users',
                            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'comms_users',
                            'value' => false,
                            'compare' => '='
                        )
                    )
                ),
                // Users are selected
                array(
                    'key' => 'comms_users',
                    'value' => serialize(strval(get_current_user_id())),
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            );
            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 24 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_search_results' );
```